# size of theme Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I'm using this theme right now, and I want to customize brown have larger :height's, but I don't want to edit the theme file.

How do you do that?

[image: Breadcrumb Area]

Comment: I need edit size in brown Area to normal , it is very big

Comment: Can you share live link?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJxRr.png

Comment: need to see your code if possible provide website url or theme name you using.

Comment: https://softbanquyen.com/hope/

Comment: Do it via a [Child Theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/).

Comment: theme Orchid Store free

Comment: I have added a solution ;) Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put on customizer > custom CSS

```
.os-breadcrumb-wrap {
    padding: 20px !important;
}
```

You can adjust the value as you need.

Comment: h1.entry-title.page-title {
    color: #1e73be!important;
}
.os-breadcrumb-wrap .mask {
    background: #fff;
}
.trail-items a {
    color: #000 !important;
}

Comment: For size >>> .footer-bottom {
    padding: 10px 0;
}

Comment: For color: .footer {
    background: #0286e7;
}

Comment: Next I need edit size to normal or custom size grid product . my website http://softbanquyen.com , i can see grid products is biggest

Comment: It's a separate issue & also I don't know the solution, you may post a new question? Any community member may provide any help/instructions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60035470/edit-size-of-theme-wordpress-css

Comment: i have posted new question